# connect() C method in Android

Tags: c, android-ndk

H!

I have source in C, which is use the `connect(peer->fd, (struct sockaddr *)dst->sockaddr, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));` C method. I use the NDK and make the jni.
My application is a msrp modul, which contain a server and a client. This method is part of the client.

The source fragment:

```
/* We're going to be the client, connect to the other peer */
dst->sockaddr = calloc(1, sizeof(dst->sockaddr));
dst->sockaddr->sin_family = AF_INET;
dst->sockaddr->sin_port = htons(dst->port);
if(inet_aton(dst->address, &(dst->sockaddr->sin_addr)) == 0) {  /* Not a numeric IP... */
    struct hostent *host = gethostbyname(dst->address); /* ...resolve name */
    if(!host) {
        local_events(MSRP_ERROR, "Invalid host for address %s",
        dst->address ? dst->address : "???.???.???.???");
            return -1;
        }
        dst->sockaddr->sin_addr = *(struct in_addr *)host->h_addr_list;
    }
    printf("----[msrp_peer_connect]---- dst->sockaddr->sin_family: %d\n", dst->sockaddr->sin_family);
    printf("----[msrp_peer_connect]---- dst->sockaddr->sin_port: %d\n", dst->sockaddr->sin_port);
    printf("----[msrp_peer_connect]---- address_lenght: %d\n", sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
    printf("----[msrp_peer_connect]---- socket description: %d\n", peer->fd);

    if(connect(peer->fd, (struct sockaddr *)dst->sockaddr, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in)) address, dst->port);
        return -1;
    }
```

and the result:

```
----[msrp_peer_connect]---- dst->sockaddr->sin_family: 2
----[msrp_peer_connect]---- dst->sockaddr->sin_port: 34330
----[msrp_peer_connect]---- address_lenght: 16
----[msrp_peer_connect]---- socket description: 5
```

I added the  in the AndroidManifest.xml.

The original source code: libmsrp

Thanks

Comment: The first Android emulator is the client and the second the server. When I connect from the first to the second everyrhing is fine. But after, when the client connect to the server this method return -1.

Comment: But, when this source use in the terminal everything is fine.

Comment: Well, why don't you check the errno variable ? it sure could give a lot of information. I would guess that errno is EADDRINUSE (you should close the socket after usage) or ECONNREFUSED (the server is not listening). Also, can you fix the indentation ?

Comment: If the Android Emulator is the server, it is don't listening any port. Are there any permission that use the socket() C API, because I use this method in the jni? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Check your if syntax :

```
if(connect(peer->fd,
       (struct sockaddr *)dst->sockaddr,
       sizeof(struct sockaddr_in)
       )
       address, dst->port);
    return -1;
}
```

There shouldn't be any semicolon at the end of the if condition. If this code ever compiles, then it will always returns -1.

Also check your indentation. It's all wrong. It could be hiding bugs, because we don't know what the last curly brace could be closing, and anyway it makes your code hard to read.

And finally, you shouldn't fail silently.

```
if(connect(peer->fd,
       (struct sockaddr *)dst->sockaddr,
       sizeof(struct sockaddr_in) == -1) {
    perror("---- [msrp_peer_connect]---- connect() failed");
    return -1;
}
```